# SearchBar and Mysql

Tags: ios, mysql

New to iOS...i am trying to do a search with a downloaded NSMutableArray table using searchbar or do need to get search from mysql table...its driving me nuts here is code below...any help would be appreciated

```
#import "VendorViewController.h"
#import "VendLocation.h"
#import "VendorDetailController.h"

@interface VendorViewController () 
{
    VendorModel *_VendorModel; NSMutableArray *_feedItems; VendLocation *_selectedLocation; UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@end

@implementation VendorViewController
//@synthesize item;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title =  @"Vendors";
    self.searchBar.hidden = YES;
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //self.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    _feedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _VendorModel = [[VendorModel alloc] init];
    _VendorModel.delegate = self;
    [_VendorModel downloadItems];

#pragma mark  Bar Button
    UIBarButtonItem *searchItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(searchButton:)];
    NSArray *actionButtonItems = @[searchItem];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;

#pragma mark  Table Refresh
    UIView *refreshView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [self.tableView insertSubview:refreshView atIndex:0]; //the tableView is a IBOutlet
    refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadDatas) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    NSMutableAttributedString *refreshString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Refreshing"];
    //add date to refresh
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, h:mm a"];
    NSString *lastUpdated = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last updated on %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lastUpdated];

    [refreshString addAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]} range:NSMakeRange(0, refreshString.length)];
    [refreshView addSubview:refreshControl];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

**#pragma mark - Search
- (void)searchButton:(id)sender{
   [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    self.searchBar.hidden = NO;
   //[self.listTableView resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    self.searchBar.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if(searchText.length == 0)
    {
        isFilltered = NO;
    } else {
        isFilltered = YES;
        filteredString = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         for(NSString *vendorName in _feedItems)
        {
            NSRange vendorNameRange = [vendorName rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if(vendorNameRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                [filteredString addObject:vendorName];
            }
        }
    }
    [self.listTableView reloadData];
}**

#pragma mark - Table
-(void)reloadDatas {
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}

-(void)itemsDownloaded:(NSMutableArray *)items
{   // This delegate method will get called when the items are finished downloading
    _feedItems = items;
    [self.listTableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark  Table Delete Button
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
           editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing
           animated:(BOOL)animated{

    [super setEditing:editing
             animated:animated];

    [self.listTableView setEditing:editing
                        animated:animated];

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [_feedItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
      /*
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![tableView save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        } */
    }
}

#pragma mark  TableView Delegate Methods
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (isFilltered) {
        return [filteredString  count];
       }
        return _feedItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    VendLocation *item = _feedItems[indexPath.row];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";
    UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    myCell.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    myCell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    if (myCell == nil) {
        myCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; }

    if (!isFilltered) {
        myCell.textLabel.text = item.vendorName;
        myCell.detailTextLabel.text = item.vendorNo;

        //Retreive an image
        UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DemoCellImage"];
        [myCell.imageView setImage:myImage];
    } else {
      myCell.textLabel.text = [filteredString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      myCell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
    }
    return myCell;
}

#pragma mark  Tableheader
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 55.0;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"VENDOR \n%lu", (unsigned long) _feedItems.count];
    NSString *newString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NASDAQ \n4,727.35"];
    NSString *newString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DOW \n17,776.80"];

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 0)];
    tableView.tableHeaderView = view; //makes header move with tablecell
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 3, tableView.frame.size.width, 45)];
    [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    NSString *string = newString;
    [label setText:string];
    [view addSubview:label];

    UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 45, 60, 1.5)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [view addSubview:separatorLineView];

    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85, 3, tableView.frame.size.width, 45)];
    label1.numberOfLines = 0;
    [label1 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
    [label1 setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    NSString *string1 = newString1;
    [label1 setText:string1];
    [view addSubview:label1];

    UIView* separatorLineView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85, 45, 60, 1.5)];
    separatorLineView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [view addSubview:separatorLineView1];

    UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(158, 3, tableView.frame.size.width, 45)];
    label2.numberOfLines = 0;
    [label2 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
    [label2 setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    NSString *string2 = newString2;
    [label2 setText:string2];
    [view addSubview:label2];

    UIView* separatorLineView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(158, 45, 60, 1.5)];
    separatorLineView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [view addSubview:separatorLineView2];

    return view;
}
```

here is my header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "VendorModel.h"

@interface VendorViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, VendorModelProtocol>
{
   // NSMutableArray *_feedItems;
    NSMutableArray *filteredString;
    BOOL isFilltered;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *listTableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

Changed Code to textDidChange

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
if(searchText.length == 0)
{
    isFilltered = NO;
} else {
    isFilltered = YES;
    filteredString = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

     for(VendLocation* vendor in _feedItems)
    {
        NSRange stringRange = [vendor.vendorName rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(stringRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            [filteredString addObject:vendor];
        }
    }
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

i changed filter too this code still no luck hit a key and crash

```
if(searchText.length == 0)
{
    isFilltered = NO;

    [filteredString removeAllObjects];
    [filteredString addObjectsFromArray:_feedItems];

} else {
    isFilltered = YES;
   // filteredString = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [filteredString removeAllObjects];
    for(NSString* string in _feedItems)
    {
        NSRange stringRange = [string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(stringRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            [filteredString addObject:string];
        }
    }
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: hope this helps                                                                                                                                                                                      2014-12-08 21:32:25.165 MySQL[14671:2386760] -[VendLocation rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe0b1678a60
2014-12-08 21:32:25.169 MySQL[14671:2386760] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[VendLocation rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe0b1678a60'
*** First throw call stack:
(

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a downloaded NSMutableArray with data in it then your search can consist of merely searching through the array and filtering out entries that do not match. You do not have to go back to MySQL.

Comment: thanks thats good too know...can someone look at code and see why i can't get my NSMutableArray filtered...when i enter text it crashes

Comment: I don't see the search bar delegate set anywhere. You should have something like `self.searchBar.delegate = self`.

Comment: Can you please provide the crash log and stack trace? It should tell you where the app is crashing.

Comment: larry its not crashing anymore i change the code in textDidChange but can't get it to work

Comment: can anybody help with getting a searchbar search on mysql table working with above code

Comment: What exactly is it doing now?

Comment: Can you please provide the crash log and stack trace? It should tell you where the app is crashing. I really can't help you anymore without that.

Comment: int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: The Console in Xcode will show you the crash dump - the log of what is happening when you crash. It will help to show what is going wrong. Please find that and include it here.